# Given 2 other arrays, populate a 3rd array with N elements following certain conditions (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

**The question text:**

> You are given a natural number N (N <= 50). You are also given 2 integer arrays x and y, both with N elements. Build the array z (also has N elements) the following way:
>
> z[i] = number of perfect squares in the interval x[1] -> x[i], if x[i]
> < y[i]
>
> z[i] = number of palindromes in the interval y[i] -> y[N], if x[i] ==
> y[i]
>
> z[i] = minim(x[1], y[N]) + minim(x[2], y[N-1]) + ... + minim(x[n],
> y[N-i+1]), if x[i] > y[i].

The sample test case:
N = 10

x = 5 2 3 7 4 2 3 9 12 4

y = 10 4 3 2 4 5 3 6 2 3

Answer to the test case:
z = 0 0 8 20 6 1 4 60 20 30

***My question: is the last condition a typo? Should it have been min(x[i], y[N-i+1]) or something else at the end? Or is the question correct and I don't understand the third condition?***

*Information: arrays start counting from 1 and end with position N.*

Sorry if code is unreadable, feel free to format it however you will. I only tried to run my code with the sample values, I haven't thought of making any test cases myself.
My answer is:

z = 0 0 8 11 6 1 4 22 26 30

My whole code for this problem:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

bool pp(ll nr) {

    if (nr >= 0) {
        ll r = sqrt(nr);

        return (r * r == nr);
    }
    
    return false;
}

bool palindrom(ll nr) {

    ll p = 0, cpy = nr;
    while (nr) {
        p = p * 10 + nr % 10;
        nr /= 10;
    }
    
    return (p == cpy);
}

int main() {

    ll N, x[51], y[51], z[51];
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) 
        cin >> x[i];
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) 
        cin >> y[i];

    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
        if (x[i] < y[i]) {
            int cnt = 0;

            for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
                if(pp(x[j]))
                    cnt++;

            z[i] = cnt;

        } else if (x[i] == y[i]) {
            int cnt = 0;

            for(int j = i; j <= N; ++j)
                if(palindrom(y[j]))
                    cnt++;

            z[i] = cnt;

        } else if (x[i] > y[i]) { //need help here
            ll s = 0;
            
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
                s += min(x[j], y[N - j + 1]);

            z[i] = s;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        cout << z[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Yep, looks like that last term should've been `y[1]` to match the rest of the sequence. But we can't tell you for sure, because we can't read the mind of whoever wrote these instructions. You should be asking them.

Comment: I'll tell my friend to ask his teacher about this problem, he had this on a test. Thanks for the answer